# Use output of waf Task in other waf Task

Tags: python, waf

I want to use the **target** of a waf Task as **source** in another waf Task, but this does not work as expected.

A simple but complete example:
I added two Tasks (`t_1`, `t_2`) I want to add as a feature and added their constraints by `before` and `after`.

- In Task `t_1` I use `src=link_task.outputs[0]` as `src` and `link_task.outputs[0].change_ext('.txt')` as `tgt` for the Task.
- But in `t_2` I want to use the output/target of `t_1` as input. I assumed I can get it by referencing `self.t_1.ouputs`, but this seems to be wrong. Why does this work for in `t_1` for the  `apply_link` Task, but not for `t_1`?

---

1. MWE: **wscript**

   ```
   from waflib import Context, Options
   from waflib import Task, TaskGen
   from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler

   def options(opt):
           opt.load('compiler_c')

   def configure(cnf):
           cnf.load('compiler_c')

   def build(bld):
           bld.program(features=['t_1', 't_2'], source='main.c', target="abc")

   class t_1(Task.Task):
       always_run = True
       run_str = 'echo ${SRC} && echo hello t_1 > ${TGT}'
       color = 'RED'


   @TaskGen.feature('t_1')
   @TaskGen.after('apply_link')
   @TaskGen.before('t_2')
   def add_t_1_task(self):
       try:
           link_task = self.link_task
       except AttributeError as err:
           print err
           return
       self.create_task('t_1', src=link_task.outputs[0], tgt=link_task.outputs[0].change_ext('.txt'))


   class t_2(Task.Task):
       always_run = True
       run_str = 'echo ${SRC}'
       color = 'RED'


   @TaskGen.feature('t_2')
   @TaskGen.after('apply_link', 't_1')
   def add_t_2_task(self):
       try:
           t_1 = self.t_1
       except AttributeError as err:
           print err
           return
       self.create_task('t_2', src=t_1.outputs[0])
   ```

---

2. Running `python waf configure build` leads to:

   ```
   user@laptop /cygdrive/c/work
   $ python waf-1.9.13 configure clean build
   Setting top to                           : /cygdrive/c/work
   Setting out to                           : /cygdrive/c/work/build
   Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
   'configure' finished successfully (0.150s)
   'clean' finished successfully (0.010s)
   Waf: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/work/build'
   'task_gen' object has no attribute 't_1' <===================== How to get this working
   [1/3] Compiling main.c
   [2/3] Linking build/abc.exe
   [3/3] Compiling build/abc.exe
   abc.exe

   Waf: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/work/build'
   'build' finished successfully (0.270s)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `before` and `after` decorators apply to task generator **methods**, not *tasks*. You should have:

```py
@TaskGen.feature('t_1')
@TaskGen.after('apply_link')
# correction: no need to use @TaskGen.before('add_t_2_task')
def add_t_1_task(self):

    # correction: you have to define self.t_1

    self.t_1 = self.create_task(
        't_1',
        self.link_task.outputs[0], 
        self.link_task.outputs[0].change_ext('.txt')
    )

@TaskGen.feature('t_2')
@TaskGen.after('apply_link', 'add_t_1_task') # correction: use method name
def add_t_2_task(self):

    # add_t-2_task is executed after add_t_1_task, so using self.t_1 is ok

    print "t_1", self.t_1
```

By the way, do not use `always_run=True` as it defeats one of waf main feature, ie only build what you need to build :)

Comment: Using `self.t_1 = self.create_task('t_1',..)` instead of `self.create_task('t_1',..)` solved the problem! Thanks. Thanks also for pointing out the error on `@TaskGen`.